# Three.JS UTF8 Loader

Tags: three.js

I'm attempting to display a 3D model in Three.JS that has been converted to UTF8 format using Won's WebGL Loader ( http://code.google.com/p/webgl-loader/ ). I don't know how to convert the metadata outputted from WebGL Loader into what Three.JS expects, and a Google Search and read through the source hasn't shed any insight. The output of WebGLLoader and input requirements for Three.JS listed below.

WebGL Loader Output:

```
MODELS['abc_normals.obj'] = {
  materials: {
  },
  decodeParams: {
    decodeOffsets: [-8192,-88,-2278,0,0,-511,-511,-511],
    decodeScales: [0.012115,0.012115,0.012115,0.000978,0.000978,0.001957,0.001957,0.001957],
  },
  urls: {
    'abc_normals.utf8': [
      { material: '',
        attribRange: [0, 8288],
        indexRange: [66304, 14914],
        bboxes: 111046,
        names: ['default', ],
        lengths: [44742, ],
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

Three.JS requirements:

```
{ scale: 0.815141, offsetX: -0.371823, offsetY: -0.011920, offsetZ: -0.416061 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using r50 like the front page of webgl-loader recommends? I don't think the output after that is compatible with the three.js loader.

Comment: I tried that version and got the following output that isn't quite in the form that Three.js expects - offsets: [77.663857,0.552530,27.608030,-0.000000,-0.000000,1.000000,1.000000,1.000000],
  scales: [182.835129,182.835129,182.835129,1.000000,1.000000,2.000000,2.000000,2.000000],  bits: [14,14,14,10,10,10,10,10]

Answer (score 0):

The output you listed is a javascript data structure but THREE.js expect JSON. To make this valid json it would need to be like this:

```
{
  "materials": {
  },
  "decodeParams": {
    "decodeOffsets": [-8192,-88,-2278,0,0,-511,-511,-511],
    "decodeScales": [0.012115,0.012115,0.012115,0.000978,0.000978,0.001957,0.001957,0.001957],
  },
  "urls": {
    "abc_normals.utf8": [
      { "material": "",
    "attribRange": [0, 8288],
    "indexRange": [66304, 14914],
    "bboxes": 111046,
    "names": ["default", ],
    "lengths": [44742, ],
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

Automatic conversion could be via loading the JS then saving model as JSON. You can try this in Chrome or Firef

```
MODELS={}
(insert your .js here)
JSON.stringify(MODELS)
```

Comment: I also want to add that when you download threejs there is a converters directory with a version of webgl-loader which works fine.